# TFS Encrypting files from other users

Tags: .net, encryption, tfs

So, my team is going to use another department's TFS Server and we want them not being able to get our files or see our code.

Is there any chance that I can encrypt the files or set a password in our branch so they can't get the files or see the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new team project for your team. Don't grant anyone you don't want to have access to your source code access to your team project.

Comment: The team is the owner of the server, they have super admin rights